# Impossible to print a graph in scilab if I try it through a callback of a function because syslin doesn't consider both arguments to be equal

Tags: scilab

how are you, I'm making a GUI in scilab based on a tutorial of Openeering people, in the GUI that I'm making I need to plot the response of a system on the right side of the figure window. It prints an initial graph of the system and I've a button to print the new graph with the parameters set in some text boxes that the GUI has, so:

the code where I initially store the data written in the text boxes is

```
//Lista ordenada de valores por defecto
values1=[0.00074,0.3,8.7,0.48,3.9,0.0035];
//Posicionamiento
l1=30;l2=100;l3=110;
for k=1:size(labels1,2)
    uicontrol("parent",sistem_graf,"style","text","string",labels1(k),"position",[l1,guih1- 
    k*20+guih1o,l2,20],"horizontalalignment","left","fontsize",14,"background",[1 1 1]);
    guientry(k)=uicontrol("parent",sistem_graf,"style","edit","string",string(values1(k)),
    "position", 
    [l3,guih1k*20+guih1o,180,20],"horizontalalignment","left","fontsize",14,"background",
    [.9 .9 .9],"tag",labels1(k));
end
```

guientry(k) is the control that names the text boxes.

The button is generated with the following code

```
//Adicionando un botón
huibutton=uicontrol(sistem_graf,"style","pushbutton",...
"position",[110 100 100 20],"String","Graficar",...
"BackgroundColor",[.9 .9 .9], "fontsize",14,...
"Callback","Calcula_Sistema");
```

and the function that is the callback of the button which is called "Calcula_Sistema" is

```
function Calcula_Sistema()
    //Lee los parámetros del sistema
    parametros=[];  
    la=findobj("tag,""La [H]"); parametros.la=la;
    ra=findobj("tag","Ra [Ohm]"); parametros.ra=ra;
    in=findobj("tag","In [A]"); parametros.in=in;
    par=findobj("tag","Par [N*m]"); parametros.par=par;
    ke=findobj("tag","Ke [V/krpm]"); parametros.ke=ke;
    j=findobj("tag","j [N/m^2]"); parametros.j=j;

    //Lee los tiempos del sistema
    /*    Tsim=[];
    Tini=findobj("tag","Tinicio [s]"); Tsim.Tini=evstr(Tini);
    Tfin=findobj("tag","Tfin [s]"); Tsim.Tini=evstr(Tfin);
    Tpaso=findobj("tag", "Tpaso [s]"); Tsim.Tpaso=evstr(Tpaso);
    */    
    Sis_Motor(parametros.la,parametros.ra,parametros.in,
    parametros.par,parametros.ke,parametros.j); 
endfunction
```

when I press the button to generate the new graph the it gives me the error

at line     8 of function Sis_Motor       ( F:\Users\valery\Documents\MEGAsync\UCV\Postgrado en Controles Industriales\Trabajo de Grado\Proyecto\Cálculos\Aplicación Scilab\Ventana.sce line 96 )
at line    18 of function Calcula_Sistema ( F:\Users\valery\Documents\MEGAsync\UCV\Postgrado en Controles Industriales\Trabajo de Grado\Proyecto\Cálculos\Aplicación Scilab\Ventana.sce line 142 )

syslin: Input arguments #2 y #3 incompatibles: Are expected of the same size.

The line 8 of the Sis_Motor function is the line 8 of the following code which is the Sis_Motor code

```
function [Wn,Zita,ftr,fta]=Sis_Motor(in,par,la,ra,ke,j)
    kt=par/in;
    n=kt/(j*la);
    b=j/10;
    d=[((b*ra+ke*kt)/(j*la)) ((b*la+j*ra)/(j*la)) 1];
    dpoly=poly(d,'s','c');
    t=[0:0.001:0.2];
    fta=syslin('c',n,dpoly);
    ftr=fta/(1+fta);
    [Wn,Zita]=damp(ftr);    
    graf=csim('step',t,ftr);
    delete(gca());
    plot2d(t,graf);
    legend('Respuesta al escalón');
    //Línea vertical.
    set(gca(),"auto_clear","off");
    graf_eje=gca();
    graf_eje.axes_bounds=[1/3,0,2/3,1];   
endfunction
```

I also tried changing the second line of Sis_Motor where is the following code

```
n=kt/(j*la);
```

for the line

```
n=[kt/(j*la) 0 0];
```

but that didn't worked and the same errors keeps appearing.

I suppose that the error comes from the processing of the inputs of the text boxes but I don't know how to solve it

Can anyone help me with that?

Update 1:

findobj wasn't find the tags exactly as  @Stephane Mottelet said, now is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findobj yields a handle to the uicontrol. To recover the numeric value of edit boxes you have to write (here e.g. for ra)

```
ra=findobj("tag","Ra [Ohm]"); parametros.ra=evstr(ra.string);
```

If it still fails maybe the object is not found and `findobj` yields an empty matrix. Just insert `disp(ra)` after the `findobj` call to be sure that the tag is (or is not) found.

Comment: Hi @Stephane Mottelet, thanks for your answer. I did that before as that way is explained in the tutorial but if I use evstr in the way you explained then the program gives me a code error saying that I'm trying to use a value from something  that is "not a structure", so,  don't know what to do next

Comment: Surely `findobj` does not find the object and yields an empty matrix. Just insert `disp(ra)` after the `findobj` call to be sure.

Comment: Mottelet I've updated the original question with the result of adding disp(ra), is under the title "Update 1:"

Comment: what happens is that scilab doesn't see the variables that I'm assigning as a structure and as a consecuence it doesn't gets the string

Comment: "Stephane Mottelet it was exactly what you said about findobj, please put that as an answer to give you the points. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Can you validate the answer ?